# print text between 2 expressions, if the end expression exists (sed -n)

Tags: shell-script, sed

So i want to display all text between 2 expressions from a file

file

```
ddd
eee
aaa
vvv
bbb
nnn
cdn
dds
aaa
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

so with the following command

```
cat $file |sed -n "/aaa/,/cdn/p"
```

i get

```
aaa
vvv
bbb
nnn
cdn
aaa
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

which is correct.

However, I only want the text "BETWEEN" the begin and end expression.
So if there is no end expression, I don't want to display the text...

so i am looking for a way to get this as a result

```
aaa
vvv
bbb
nnn
cdn
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print lines between start & end pattern, but if end pattern does not exist, don't print](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523223/print-lines-between-start-end-pattern-but-if-end-pattern-does-not-exist-don)

Comment: You are on the right track. If the output doesn't end in second expression (cdn) then pipe you result to : tac | sed  '1,/aaa/d' | tac

Comment: There's a lot of things you might mean given that aaa and cdn can appear multiple times in your input. Do you want to print from a) the first aaa to the first cdn, b) the first aaa to the last cdn, c) the last aaa to the first cdn after it, d) the last aaa to the last cdn, e) every closest aaa-cdn pairs, f) nested pairs as well as the surrounding pairs, or g) something else?

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), this is not [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), but it's quite more readable than `sed`:

```
perl -0nE 'say $& if /\baaa\b.*?\bcdn\b/s' file
aaa
vvv
bbb
nnn
```

With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)\baaa\b.*?\bcdn\b' file
aaa
vvv
bbb
nnn
```

Check [grep -Pzo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/465183)

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation for your sed solution, especially the curly brackets. Thanks

Comment: `-0` is for nul-delimited records, you likely want `-0777` to slurp the whole input instead. You also likely want `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Comment: Yes, added stronger regex. For `-0` it's a kind of hack and easier to remember

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ sed -n '/aaa/,/cdn/ { /aaa/h; //!H; /cdn/ { g; p; }; }' file
aaa
vvv
bbb
nnn
cdn
```

This uses the same range as in your attempted command, but within that range, we save the line to the hold-space if it matches `aaa`, append the line to the hold-space if it does not match `aaa`, and fetch the hold space and print it if it matches `cdn`.

This would extract the "tightest" region of `aaa`...`cdn` in a file where `aaa` or `cdn` (or both) are repeated, meaning that an input like

```
111
111
aaa
222
222
aaa
333
333
cdn
444
444
cdn
```

would give you

```
aaa
333
333
cdn
```

... rather than the lines from the *first* `aaa` to the *last* `cdn`.

---

Another way of formulating the same thing without `-n`:

```bash
sed -e '/aaa/,/cdn/!d' -e '/aaa/h' -e '//!H' -e '/cdn/!d' -e g file
```